# How to print Object values

Tags: apex, api

How to print only the CuID value rather than the whole object?

```
string response = '{"odata.metadata": "https://episerver.test.com/ERP101100/api/v1/Customers/$metadata#Epicor.RestApi.Customers","cust": [{"Org": "XXY0000","CuID": "CU-0001","CuNum": 1,"Name": "Healthcare Unit"},{"Org": "XXY0001","CuID": "CU-0001","CuNum": 2,"Name": "Manufacturing Unit"}]}';

Map<String, Object> results = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(response);

List<Object> values = (List<Object>) results.get('cust');

for (Object value: values) {
    //print all value info
    system.debug(value);

    //print CuID only
}
```

Result

```
{CuID=CU-0001, CuNum=1, Name=Healthcare Unit, Org=XXY0000}
{CuID=CU-0001, CuNum=2, Name=Manufacturing Unit, Org=XXY0001}
```

Comment: so, what is the question? Please use [edit]

Comment: Updated, How to print only the CuID value rather than the whole object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you need to do

```
for (Object value: values) {
  system.debug(((Map<String,Object>)o).get('CuID'));
}
```

That is, `value` is a map of `<String,Object>` so you need to cast that to a new map and then fetch the map entry by key (`CuID`). Map keys are case sensitive